# chainlit AsyncLangchainCallbackHandler 'Message' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, chatbot, langchain, huggingface, large-language-model

Received this error message 'Message' object has no attribute 'replace'.

This is part of Q&A chatbot based on local documents. The chatbot started successfully but after first interaction like "Hello", I received the error message.

Below is the code. I believe the error is on the AsyncLangchainCallbackHandler

```
@cl.on_message
async def main(message):
 chain=cl.user_session.get("chain")
 cb = cl.AsyncLangchainCallbackHandler(
  stream_final_answer=True, answer_prefix_tokens=["FINAL","ANSWER"]
  )
#  cb = cl.AsyncLangchainCallbackHandler()
 cb.ansert_reached=True
 res=await chain.acall(message, callbacks=[cb])
 print("LangChain response:", res)
 answer=res["result"]
 sources=res["source_documents"]

 if sources:
  answer+=f"\nSources: "+str(str(sources))
 else:
  answer+=f"\nNo Sources found"

 await cl.Message(content=answer).send()
```

Answer (score 2):

This is now resolved by the following.

```
res=await chain.acall(message.content, callbacks=[cb])
```